# Can Kafka Sink Connectors include the record timestamp as the payload stored at the storage

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, s3-kafka-connector

I'm using both the S3 and JDBC sink connectors and I'm experiencing a bit of weird behavior about my data being stored. For some reconciliation I would really like to keep the either the Kafka Ingestion time or the record producing time into the data that is stored in the Sink system.

I was looking in the documentation and I did not find this.
I'm using the Confluent connectors but I could also use other connectors like Camel if it would allow me to do this.

Can someone give me some pointers on this?

UPDATE:
Based on the good feedback from onecricketeer I understood I should be looking at this:
https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/connect/transforms/insertfield.html#insertfield

And I also saw this example:
[Kafka connect consumer referencing offset and storing in message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757391/kafka-connect-consumer-referencing-offset-and-storing-in-message)

I will test it but do I understand correctly for example that in theory I could do something like this:

```
"transforms": "InsertField",
"transforms.InsertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
"transforms.InsertField.offset.field": "recordOffset"
"transforms.InsertField.partition.field": "recordPartition"
"transforms.InsertField.timestamp.field": "recordTimestamp"
```

And this would create me 3 new properties in the record called recordOffset, recordPartition and recordTimestamp containing the values described.

And If I wanted to ensure that the values would always be there or fail I would need to do (not sure I understood the suffix part):

```
"transforms": "InsertField",
"transforms.InsertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
"!transforms.InsertField.offset.field": "recordOffset"
"!transforms.InsertField.partition.field": "recordPartition"
"!transforms.InsertField.timestamp.field": "recordTimestamp"
```

Comment: You'd want to look at the Simple Message Transforms for inserting (or relocating) the record timestamp into the value portion of the message

Comment: Thank you. I believe what I want is exactly that you could give the answer for me to mark it as correct Answer
https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/connect/transforms/insertfield.html#insertfield

Comment: I have one more question based on the follow up
looking at this response for example (and something I will test) https://stackoverflow.com/a/61758800/5685482 I believe I could use for example the offset but is there a way to ensure the offset will be called something specific?
the same as for the static?

Comment: `offset.field` would be the key of the numeric offset value... I see your comment about the `!` operator, but I've never really seen that used. However, the docs say "suffix", and you're doing a prefix here

Comment: I ended up not using the suffix because it was not needed.
but you are correct I should have read it properly :) suffix/prefix are quite different :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `@OneCricketeer` says, the `InsertField` Single Message Transform does the job here. Here's a sample S3 sink configuration using it:

```json
{
          "connector.class"        : "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
          "storage.class"          : "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
          "s3.region"              : "us-west-2",
          "s3.bucket.name"         : "rmoff-smt-demo-01",
          "topics"                 : "customers,transactions",
          "tasks.max"              : "4",
          "flush.size"             : "16",
          "format.class"           : "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
          "schema.generator.class" : "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
          "schema.compatibility"   : "NONE",
          "partitioner.class"      : "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
          "transforms"                          : "insertTS,formatTS",
          "transforms.insertTS.type"            : "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
          "transforms.insertTS.timestamp.field" : "messageTS",
          "transforms.formatTS.type"            : "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
          "transforms.formatTS.format"          : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS",
          "transforms.formatTS.field"           : "messageTS",
          "transforms.formatTS.target.type"     : "string"        
        }
```

Note that it also uses `TimestampConverter` to format the timestamp in a string - by default it's an epoch.

Your question prompted me to [write this up properly](https://rmoff.net/2020/12/08/twelve-days-of-smt-day-1-insertfield-timestamp/) and record a little tutorial - you can see it here: https://youtu.be/3Gj_SoyuTYk